# How to move button randomly on the screen on click?

Tags: android, animation, button, random, move

So I am trying to get a button on the screen to move when it is clicked. It currently is setup to count clicks, but I want the button to move everytime you click it. I have tried a translate animation, which didn't work because the button still fires the onClick from the original location.

I leared about ObjectAnimator and have been trying to get that to work since the onClick event will move with the button, but I can't seem to get it to work. I also need help getting the button to move randomly within it's layout parent. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here's my current Object Animator Code. Please note it is not setup for random movement yet, since I am unsure of how to get it to do that:

```
ObjectAnimator  animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btnCount, "xTranslate", 0f, 50f);
                    ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btnCount, "TranslateY", 0f, 50f);

                       AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
                       animSet.playSequentially(animX, animY);
                       animSet.setDuration(500);


                   animSet.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get this done will be as given below. Do this on your `onClick` listener.

```
btnCount.animate().xBy(10).yBy(10);
```

With regards to random, I guess you can use something as simple as this... In any case, you may have to take care of reaching the screen limit.

```
Random r = new Random();
btnCount.animate().xBy(r.nextInt(10)+1).yBy(r.nextInt(10)+1);
```

Comment: But the code you have given will not animate the button. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: yea just trying to figure out how to move the button to a new location. I don't have to see the button actually moving, just going from one location, to a random location on the screen.

Comment: What is button count?

Answer (score 0):

Found that using the below did what I needed it to:

```
Random r = new Random();
                        int buttonHeight;
                        int buttonWidth;
                        buttonHeight = btnCount.getHeight();
                        buttonWidth = btnCount.getWidth();
                        int xLeft = r.nextInt(480 - buttonHeight);
                        int yUp = r.nextInt(800 - buttonWidth);
                        int xRight = r.nextInt(480 + buttonHeight);
                        int yDown = r.nextInt(800 + buttonHeight);

                        btnCount.setX(xLeft);       
                        btnCount.setY(yUp);
                        btnCount.setX(xRight);
                        btnCount.setY(yDown);
```